# Redirect output of child process spawned from Rust

Tags: process, io, rust

I need to redirect output of a spawned child process. This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
Command::new(cmd)
    .args(&["--testnet",
            "--fast",
            format!("&>> {}", log_path).as_str()])
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
    .spawn()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly use a file as output without intermediate copying from a pipe, you have to pass the file descriptor. The code is platform-specific, but with conditional compilation you can make it work on Windows too.

```
let f = File::create("foo.log").unwrap();
let fd = f.as_raw_fd();
// from_raw_fd is only considered unsafe if the file is used for mmap
let out = unsafe {Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd)};
let child = Command::new("foo")
    .stdout(out)
    .spawn().unwrap();
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this code working on Windows also?
From doc, I only found for unix.

Comment: I already said so "but with conditional compilation you can make it work on Windows too.", just use the `handle` equivalents instead of `fd`

Comment: Thanks, just missed windows module in `std::os`, that is why asked

Answer (score 9):

You can't redirect output with `>` when starting another program like that. Operators like `>`, `>>`, `|` and similar ones are interpreted by your shell and are not a native functionality of starting programs. Since the `Command` API doesn't emulate a shell, this won't work. So instead of passing it in `args` you have to use other methods of the `process` API to achieve what you want.

#### Short lived program

If the program to start is usually finished immediately, you might just want to wait until it's done and collect its output then. Then you can simply use the [`Command::output()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output):

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

let output = Command::new("rustc")
    .args(&["-V", "--verbose"])
    .output()?;

let mut f = File::create("rustc.log")?;
f.write_all(&output.stdout)?;
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e8e9770e39abf7d4849b02b227239d20&version=stable&backtrace=0))

*Note*: the code above has to be in a function that returns a `Result` in order for the `?` operator to work (it just passes errors up).

#### Long lived program

But maybe your program is not short lived and you don't want to wait until it's finished before doing anything with the output. In that case you should capture stdout and call [`Command::spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.spawn). Then you can access the [`ChildStdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ChildStdout.html) which implements `Read`:

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;

let child = Command::new("ping")
    .args(&["-c", "10", "google.com"])
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()?;

let mut f = File::create("ping.log")?;
io::copy(&mut child.stdout.unwrap(), &mut f)?;
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=76e27831e8c28adccd252d9cb09827e8&version=stable&backtrace=0))

That way, `ping.log` is written on the fly every time the command outputs new data.

Comment: Thanks, 
I already tried `io::copy` but it is not working for me, looks like I am missing somethings.
I am trying to watch log with `tail` but stays empty

Comment: @KostyaKrivomaz Have you tried `tail -f`? Otherwise the view won't update. And I just tried, and it does indeed work for me...

Comment: Yeap, tried with `-f`. Just executed your example, and still nothing. 
There is some problem on my side, down further, will continue searching. Any way, thanks.

Comment: I think the right argument for `ping` is `-c` instead of `-n` 

Answer (score 6):

They have added a new (in 7/6/2017 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/42133) `std::process::Stdio::from` function that also accepts files and works on both windows and unix systems.
example:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let f = File::create("path/to/some/log.log").unwrap();
    let mut cmd = Command::new("some command")
        .stdout(std::process::Stdio::from(f))
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    cmd.wait().unwrap();
}
```